# (Discussion) How could I build on Barbara Kruger's style/aesthetics, alter it/add on it, making it a style of its "own"?

Tags: art

I've been a huge of Barbara Kruger's works for a long time, and as someone who also really loves archive, conceptual art (with bold captions), typo (meshed with graphic imagery to give it a new meaning/reinterpret it), I always wondered how I could build on Barbara Kruger's influence and style and maybe tweak some stuff (maybe through change of color, effects, addition of layers...) to make a new style of its own that built on the previous one. As I know the power of internet can be strong and ideas can flow out from all sides, I'm open to discussing about it and see how art inflows can go! :)

See attached a representative picture of her form of art.[image: f]

Comment: Hi Raf! Not sure how your question will do but this is something you could discuss in our chatroom :)

Comment: Also, suggested reframing if your question gets close votes: how can I reinvest vintage styles in a modern way? (or something along those lines)

Comment: This is not vintage. BK is still alive and her works are selling (sometimes) for $ millions at auction. Intriguing question, but not particularly related to graphic design? I would still not vote to close this.

Comment: @Raf Reyes: I've seen her work appropriated and/or modified a few times. Also similar in approach to some of John Baldessari's or Ed Ruscha's work. West coast conceptual word & image kind of work

Comment: @Lucian ah! I'm not familiar with her work, visually seemed vintage is all :) (I should have read the type!) I'm not sure if I'd feel comfortable reappropriating a designer's current work. On top of that, it seems pretty niche so finding relevant uses seems like it would be challenging. Anyways, interested to see where this goes!